# Oppty Field Dissapeared from Campaign Page

Tags: opportunity, administration, campaign, campaign-influence

When creating Campaigns, the Opty field has disappeared from the specific campaign's page.

Campaign Hierarchy, Open Activities, Activity History, Attachments, and Campaign Members all appear when clicked into a specific campaign, but Opportunities does not.

Any quick fixes to this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you check your page layouts. It is most likely something that was removed from the page layouts.

When editing page layouts for the campaign object go into "related lists" within the toolbox at the top of the editor, then just drag the oppty "related list" back out and drop it down at the bottom of the page layout.

If you do not have admin capabilities please alert your Salesforce admin to see if this can be fixed.

Comment: The user also could have lost privileges to the field itself. I would suggest also checking the profile if the field is on the page layout.